# query.setMaxResults() causes problems on toplink

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, toplink

I am using JPA (toplink) and trying to restrict the number of rows returned by a JPQL query, so I've used `Query.setMaxResults` method, but It throws the following error:

```
Exception [TOPLINK-6121] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The query has not been defined correctly, the expression builder is missing.  For sub and parallel queries ensure the queries builder is always on the left.
```

Here's the query:

```
select distinct d.deptName from Departement d join d.employees e where e.empId in (select distinct a.employee.empId from ApprovedEmpls a join a.NewEmps o)
```

Comment: Are you sure the `setMaxResults` causes the problem? Have you tried if it works, without it?

Comment: Yes, it is working without it.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the query will fail the same without the maxResults?

Seems to be an issue with the sub-selects, try removing or changing it (why does it join NewEmps and not use it at all?).  You could also use a native SQL query as a workaround.

You should consider upgrading TopLink Essentials to EclipseLink (TopLink 11g).

Comment: It is working fine, and yest I should consider using JOINs instead.